# How to count SO memory

Tags: java-native-interface

I can't find the relevant so occupancy under proc/pid/maps. In the app, I use System.loadlibrary("***") to load a so named ***. During the running of the program, I can normally Use him, make sure it has been loaded and is in use, and it has not been unloaded, but I can't find it in the maps, what is the reason, then where is this part of the memory, is it still in the so mmap memory? how do i count it

I checked the proc/pid/maps file, and I have root privileges, but I still can’t find the loading status of the corresponding so. May I ask where it is loaded and how to count it?

Comment: Too vague to answer. Please edit your question with the output of `/proc/pid/maps` and try running java with the environment variable `LD_DEBUG=all` set to see when/how it loads libraries.